# Access value of variable from if statement Javascript with event onclick

Tags: javascript, scope

I have the following snippet of code:

```
var j=4;
    var x;
    if(j>5){
        x=8;
    }else if(j<5){
        x=1;
    }
    function write(){
        document.write(x);
    }
```

UPDATE: I am having a problem that when I have a button call the function write() it will not print out 1 when it is clicked, it will print out nothing. Calling the function write() separately works, but how do I get that to change for when it is called on by the onclick event?

Comment: That should print `1` !

Comment: you snippit already prints 1 as the value of x

Comment: Have you tried passing it into the function as an argument?

Comment: Just call `function Write()` in snippet with argument x

Comment: I think he is trolling

Comment: what i am seriously not getting any output when I press the button that calls write().

Comment: ah, so when I changed the name of the function it started to work. I feel incredibly stupid.

Answer (score 1):

You must call the function:

```
function write(){
    document.write(x);
}

var j=4,
    x;

if(j>5){
    x=8;
}else if(j<5){
    x=1;
}

write();
```

Here is a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5MxZB/)